# SQLite date compare very strange

Tags: sqlite, datetime, date, compare

I store dates as String in my database, in this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
```

and in my db I have rows (all columns are strings):

```
       COL1        |     COL2
----------------------------------
'2012-06-21 18:53' |   'item1'
'2012-06-21 18:54' |   'item2'
'2012-06-21 18:55' |   'item3'
```

Now I want to compare these stored dates (well, strings), and this is very very strange:

this query

```
select * 
  from MyTable 
  where col1 > Datetime('2012-06-21 18:53')
```

returns 2 rows (all except first) - this is correct.

but this query

```
select * 
      from MyTable 
      where col1 >= Datetime('2012-06-21 18:53')
```

return also only 2 rows, but it should return all 3 rows, as I used `>=` instead of `>`.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlite> SELECT datetime('2012-06-21 18:53');
2012-06-21 18:53:00
```

datetime() returns a string in a different format than the fields of your database. You can use just the string for WHERE, e.g.

```
select * 
      from MyTable 
      where col1 >= '2012-06-21 18:53'
```

Comment: exactly same thing i noticed few seconds before! Funny...Well, still cant understand it, as format of my string is one of supported, look here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM. Anyway, it works...